# Python SMTP socket.gaierror: [Errorno -2] Name or Service not found

Tags: python, sockets, email

I am using SMTP connection to connect and send email but I get SMTP socket.gaierror: [Errorno -2] Name or Service not found. here is my code

```
from smtplib import SMTP
import datetime

debuglevel = 0

smtp = SMTP()
smtp.set_debuglevel(debuglevel)
smtp.connect('MY.MAIL.SERVER', 587)
smtp.login('USERNAME@DOMAIN', 'PASSWORD')

from_addr = "ann@abcsystems.com"
to_addr = "minna@abcsystems.com"

subj = "hello"

message_text = "Hello\nThis is a test mail from server\n\n"

msg = "From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s" 
        % ( from_addr, to_addr, subj, message_text )

smtp.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr, msg)
smtp.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(
    socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('MY.MAIL.SERVER', 587))
```

If it throws `gai error` again, then try pinging `MY.MAIL.SERVER` from the local machine.

Comment: add an entry in `/etc/hosts` with the hostname `MY.MAIL.SERVER` and the ip address returned by ping command and see if it works...